# Как сделать проверку по значениям массива в объекта массива?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет, есть такой код:

```
        const city = [
        {
            city: ['Уфа', 'Рязань', 'Омск'],
            usual: '980',
            fast: 'Уточните у оператора'
        },
{
            city: ['Улан-Удэ', 'Челябинск', 'Астрахань'],
            usual: '900',
            fast: 'Уточните у оператора'
        }
]
```

Пользователь выбирает в списке свой город. Каждый город находится в определенной зоне, зон много, каждая из них содержит города. В данном случае каждый объект массивы city это зона, а city.city города в ней. Я хочу получить значение usual из той зоны, где находится город, который выбрал пользователь.
Пробовал с помощью цикла for. Но выдает ошибку!

```
    for (let i in city) {
    for (let v in city[i].city) {
        if (secondCity === city[i].city[v]) {
            delivery === 'fast' ? pay = city[i].fast : pay = city[i].usual
        }
    }
}
```

Что делаю неправильно или как лучше реализовать перебор по этим городам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так?

```js
const zones = [
  {
    cities: ['Уфа', 'Рязань', 'Омск'],
    usual: 980
  },
  {
    cities: ['Улан-Удэ', 'Челябинск', 'Астрахань'],
    usual: 900
  }
];

const city = 'Омск';

zones.forEach((zone) => {
  if (zone.cities.includes(city)) {
    console.log(zone.usual);
  }
});
```

Comment: Да, спасибо))))

Comment: @DanilGallyamshin, не за что, если данный ответ решил Вашу проблему, то сверху слева от него (ответа) есть галочка, нажмите на неё, если у других пользователей появится такой же вопрос, как и у Вас, то они смогут быстро найти на него решение.

Comment: delivery === 'fast' ? pay = city[i].fast : pay = city[i].usual а это как вписать внутрь?

Comment: внутри `if`'a => `delivery === 'fast' ? pay = zone.fast : pay = zone.usual`

Comment: script.js:80 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at script.js:80

Comment: @DanilGallyamshin, внимательно смотрите какие аргументы используете